Logic Apps - Log Analytics Data Collector Is Not Accepting Array Variables
I added the Azure Log Analytics Data Collector connector in my Logic Apps workflow and I tried to add an array variable called result to it but it is not showing in the list. Only boolean and string variables are showing as seen in the screenshot below.

But all the array variables are not showing up. In the screenshot below, the first 3 variables are all arrays but I can't seem to add them in the connector.

Is this a limitation of the connector?

You can transform the array variable value to a string using the join function.
Example:




Result:

